# How to configure Sublime text to support both spaces and tabs for indentation

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text for JavaScript development where I use tabs for indentation.

But, for Python development, I need to use spaces (per PEP-8). So what config directives should I change to support both.

(I am fairly new to Sublime Text)

Answer (score 2):

You can create syntax specific configurations. `Preferences -> Settings - More ->Syntax Specific - User`. Add the following configuration `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false`, setting the boolean as appropriate.